# Generated .po file has msgstr "" after makemessages

Tags: python, django, localization, web, multilingual

I am using Django localization API for offering multilingual feature to my website. But after generating .po file all msgstr are blank. I did not get any translated strings.

Following is the setting.py configuration

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'framework.botdetection_middleware.AvoidBotsMiddleware',
    'framework.cl_redirect.MainSiteRedirect',
    'framework.ssl_redirect.SSLRedirect',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',    
    'framework.wlabel_middleware.CustomDomainMiddleware',    
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'social.apps.django_app.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)

# Implementation of Localiztion

# Path to locale folder
LOCALE_PATHS = (
     os.path.join(APP_DIR, 'locale').replace('\\', '/'),
)

# The language your website is starting in
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

# The languages you are supporting
ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('fr', ugettext('French')),
    ('pl', ugettext('Polish')),
)

# Use internationalization
USE_I18N = True

# Use localization
USE_L10N = True
```

I use the following command for creating .po file.

```
django-admin makemessages --locale=fr --extension=html --ignore=env --ignore=*.py
```

And following is the output i got

```
msgid "Change Payment Method"
msgstr ""

msgid "Return to Purchase Details"
msgstr
```

Am i missing something. Also how can i load translated version of my website without using url.py

Answer (score 0):

That is the normal behaviour. You have to translate the `msgstr` parts yourself and compile it back using `manage.py compilemessages`. RTFM.

Comment: You mean i need a translator to translate those string into desired language. Is there not any way to get them using some api. I mean i have seen examples where after generating message file they shows translated version in msgstr.

Comment: @ArjunSingh Yes, it is not a machine translating tool but a tool for getting all the strings in one place so a translator can translate them. The translated results will appear when you have once translated them and run `makemessages` again to make updates to the translations file, then all the old translations will be included again and it might give an impression that Django did the translating for you while actually they were translated and inserted beforehand.

Comment: Do you have any idea about tool or something which could translate all .po files in a go.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to translate templates outside the template folder.